# Merging Two Columns In SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can i alter the table and put columns account2,amoun2 under account and amount columns using sql? I have a report that comes this way and i put to put them under just the first two columns. I am using access's sql view to perform this. Thank you

```
Account Amount Account2 Amount2
1234576  4      1234576    4
4444444  10     4564888    11
456789   2      456789      2
000000   1      1111111     6
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want `union all`?

```
select account, amount
from t
union all
select account2, amount2
from t;
```

Comment: How did you guess what OP asks? I have understood the question only after reading your  answer.

Comment: I need to put columns Account2, and amount 2 all under columns Account, Amount. That you Gordon that worked.